# Qt MinGW QThread performance bad

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opengl, mingw

We're currently working on a simple 3D engine with OpenGL and almost everything is ready for our final university presentation. Im usually working with MSVC2015 x64 compiler and everything works fine, build speed is fast and executable performance too. 
However since the latest changes we've made, the physics thread is extremely slow on MinGW 4.9.2 x86 and some variables like delta are strangely 0, even though the thread is working.

When I switch back to MSVC, it works like a charm Its hard to describe, so I apologize.

Heres a GIF for better understandability: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ten1E.jpg

As you can see, the spheres are moving incredibly choppy. On MSVC they are moving perfectly smooth and delta is usually 0.007831ms. On MinGW delta is 0ms and sometimes, just sometimes its extremely high like ~5ms. We have absolutely no idea what it causes. I suspect the compiler optimizes something? I have no idea...

```
void PhysicsThread::run(){
    qDebug() << "SUCCESSFULLY STARTED UP PHYSICS-SIMULATION";
    forever{
        mutex.lock();
        qDebug() << "RUNNING PHYSICS-SIMULATION";
        runSimulation();
        if(stop){
            mutex.unlock();
            break;
        }
        if(bPause){
            pauseManager.wait(&mutex);
        }
        mutex.unlock();
    }
}

void PhysicsThread::runSimulation(){
    auto startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Collision Border
    for(int i = 0 ; i < pobjectsSphere.size() ; i++) {

        PhysicsSphere* op = pobjectsSphere.at(i);
        if(op->getIsMovable()){
            if(op->getX()-(op->getSize()) < minx ){
                if(op->getVelocityX() < 0){
                    op->setVelocityX(-op->getVelocityX());
                }else{
                    op->setVelocityX(op->getVelocityX());
                }
            }else if(op->getX()+(op->getSize()) > maxx) {
                if(op->getVelocityX() > 0){
                    op->setVelocityX(-op->getVelocityX());
                }else{
                    op->setVelocityX(op->getVelocityX());
                }
            }

            if(op->getY()-(op->getSize()) < miny){
                if(op->getVelocityY() < 0){
                    op->setVelocityY(-op->getVelocityY() * op->getRemainingEnergy());
                }else{
                    op->setVelocityY(op->getVelocityY());
                }
            }else{
                if(op->getY()+(op->getSize()) > maxy){
                    if(op->getVelocityY() > 0){
                        op->setVelocityY(-op->getVelocityY());
                    }else{
                        op->setVelocityY(op->getVelocityY());
                    }
                }

                // Gravity
                op->setVelocityY(op->getVelocityY() + g*deltaTimeMS*op->getMass());
            }

            if(op->getZ()-(op->getSize()) < minz){
                if(op->getVelocityZ() < 0){
                    op->setVelocityZ(-op->getVelocityZ());
                }else{
                    op->setVelocityZ(op->getVelocityZ());
                }
            }else if(op->getZ()+(op->getSize()) > maxz){
                if(op->getVelocityZ() > 0){
                    op->setVelocityZ(-op->getVelocityZ());
                }else{
                    op->setVelocityZ(op->getVelocityZ());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Collision Sphere on Sphere
    for(int i = 0 ; i < pobjectsSphere.size() ; i++) {
        PhysicsSphere* op1 = pobjectsSphere.at(i);
        for(int j = i ; j < pobjectsSphere.size() ; j++) {
            PhysicsSphere* op2 = pobjectsSphere.at(j);

            // Sphere on Sphere
            if(i != j && Collision::SphereVersusSphere(op1->getX() ,op1->getY() ,op1->getZ() ,op1->getSize() ,op2->getX() ,op2->getY() ,op2->getZ() ,op2->getSize())){

                double tempX (op1->getX() - op2->getX());
                double tempY (op1->getY() - op2->getY());
                double tempZ (op1->getZ() - op2->getZ());

                double norm = sqrt(tempX*tempX + tempY*tempY + tempZ*tempZ);

                tempX = tempX / norm;
                tempY = tempY / norm;
                tempZ = tempZ / norm;

                double a1 = (op1->getVelocityX() * tempX) + (op1->getVelocityY() * tempY) + (op1->getVelocityZ() * tempZ);
                double a2 = (op2->getVelocityX() * tempX) + (op2->getVelocityY() * tempY) + (op2->getVelocityZ() * tempZ);

                double optimizedP = (2.0 * (a1 - a2)) / (op1->getMass() + op2->getMass());

                // fix
                optimizedP = std::abs(optimizedP);

                // 0.9 Verlusst
                if(op1->getIsMovable()){
                    op1->setVelocityX( op1->getVelocityX() + (optimizedP * op2->getMass() * tempX) * (op1->getRemainingEnergy()*op2->getRemainingEnergy()));
                    op1->setVelocityY( op1->getVelocityY() + (optimizedP * op2->getMass() * tempY) * (op1->getRemainingEnergy()*op2->getRemainingEnergy()));
                    op1->setVelocityZ( op1->getVelocityZ() + (optimizedP * op2->getMass() * tempZ) * (op1->getRemainingEnergy()*op2->getRemainingEnergy()));
                }

                if(op2->getIsMovable()){
                    op2->setVelocityX( op2->getVelocityX() - (optimizedP * op1->getMass() * tempX) * (op1->getRemainingEnergy()*op2->getRemainingEnergy()));
                    op2->setVelocityY( op2->getVelocityY() - (optimizedP * op1->getMass() * tempY) * (op1->getRemainingEnergy()*op2->getRemainingEnergy()));
                    op2->setVelocityZ( op2->getVelocityZ() - (optimizedP * op1->getMass() * tempZ) * (op1->getRemainingEnergy()*op2->getRemainingEnergy()));
                }

                if(!op1->getIsMovable() && op2->getIsMovable()){
                    op2->setX(op2->getX() - op1->getVelocityX() * deltaTimeMS);
                    op2->setY(op2->getY() - op1->getVelocityY() * deltaTimeMS);
                    op2->setZ(op2->getZ() - op1->getVelocityZ() * deltaTimeMS);

                    op1->setVelocityX(0.0);
                    op1->setVelocityY(0.0);
                    op1->setVelocityZ(0.0);

                }else if(op1->getIsMovable() && !op2->getIsMovable()){
                    op1->setX(op1->getX() - op2->getVelocityX() * deltaTimeMS);
                    op1->setY(op1->getY() - op2->getVelocityY() * deltaTimeMS);
                    op1->setZ(op1->getZ() - op2->getVelocityZ() * deltaTimeMS);

                    op2->setVelocityX(0.0);
                    op2->setVelocityY(0.0);
                    op2->setVelocityZ(0.0);
                }


                op1->setX(op1->getX() + op1->getVelocityX() * deltaTimeMS);
                op1->setY(op1->getY() + op1->getVelocityY() * deltaTimeMS);
                op1->setZ(op1->getZ() + op1->getVelocityZ() * deltaTimeMS);

                op2->setX(op2->getX() + op2->getVelocityX() * deltaTimeMS);
                op2->setY(op2->getY() + op2->getVelocityY() * deltaTimeMS);
                op2->setZ(op2->getZ() + op2->getVelocityZ() * deltaTimeMS);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i < pobjectsSphere.size() ; i++) {
        PhysicsSphere* op1 = pobjectsSphere.at(i);
        for(int j = 0 ; j < pobjectsBox.size() ; j++) {
            PhysicsBox* op2 = pobjectsBox.at(j);



            if(Collision::SphereVersusBox( op1->getX() ,op1->getY() ,op1->getZ() ,op1->getSize() ,op2->getMinX()+op2->getX() ,op2->getMinY()+op2->getY() ,op2->getMinZ()+op2->getZ() ,op2->getMaxX()+op2->getX() ,op2->getMaxY()+op2->getY() ,op2->getMaxZ()+op2->getZ())){

                if((op1->getX()+op1->getSize()) > op2->getMinX() && op1->getX() < op2->getMinX()+op2->getX()){

                    if(op1->getVelocityX() > 0){
                        op1->setVelocityX(-op1->getVelocityX());
                    }
                }
                if((op1->getX()-op1->getSize()) < op2->getMaxX() && op1->getX() > op2->getMaxX()+op2->getX()){
                    if(op1->getVelocityX() < 0){
                        op1->setVelocityX(-op1->getVelocityX());
                    }
                }

                if((op1->getY()+op1->getSize()) > op2->getMinY() && op1->getY() < op2->getMinY()+op2->getY()){
                    if(op1->getVelocityY() > 0){
                        op1->setVelocityY(-op1->getVelocityY());
                    }
                }
                if((op1->getY()-op1->getSize()) < op2->getMaxY() && op1->getY() > op2->getMaxY()+op2->getY()){

                    if(op1->getVelocityY() < 0){
                        op1->setVelocityY(-op1->getVelocityY());
                    }
                }

                if((op1->getZ()+op1->getSize()) > op2->getMinZ() && op1->getZ() < op2->getMinZ()+op2->getZ()){
                    if(op1->getVelocityZ() > 0){
                        op1->setVelocityZ(-op1->getVelocityZ());
                    }
                }
                if((op1->getZ()-op1->getSize()) < op2->getMaxZ() && op1->getZ() > op2->getMaxZ()+op2->getZ()){
                    if(op1->getVelocityZ() < 0){
                        op1->setVelocityZ(-op1->getVelocityZ());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Move
    for(int i = 0 ; i < pobjectsSphere.size() ; i++) {
        PhysicsSphere* op = pobjectsSphere.at(i);
        if(op->getIsMovable()){
            op->setX(op->getX() + op->getVelocityX()*deltaTimeMS);
            op->setY(op->getY() + op->getVelocityY()*deltaTimeMS);
            op->setZ(op->getZ() + op->getVelocityZ()*deltaTimeMS);
        }else{
            op->setVelocityX(0.0);
            op->setVelocityY(0.0);
            op->setVelocityZ(0.0);
        }

    }
    if(pauseTickTime > 0.0){
        this->msleep(pauseTickTime);
    }
    auto endTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> time = endTime - startTime;
    deltaTimeNS = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(time).count();
    deltaTimeMS = deltaTimeNS / 1000000.0;
    //qDebug() << "DeltaT NS: " << deltaTimeNS << " DeltaT MS: " << deltaTimeMS;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with either `QThread` or mingw, you're misdiagnosing the problem. Remember that `QThread` is a very simple handle to a native thread. It had nothing to do with what you're seeing.

Your time step logic is fundamentally flawed. You're assuming that `startTime` and `endTime` will differ. **They don't have to - you've just made a test case for yourself that demonstrates this.** There's nothing in the API of the clock that you're using that would guarantee that you'll get results that differ when you call it twice.

Your physics engine should operate with a constant time step, and an internal time that you add to on every time step. When you start the simulation, set the engine's time to system time. Then keep calculating the steps in the engine for as long as it lags behind the real time. Once it catches up, perform a display update. And repeat.

Comment: I assume you refer to Glenn Fiedlers article "Free the Physics"?
Actually I foud the culprit that caused my delta to be 0. ostd::chrono::high_resolution_clock can be a synonym for system_clock.
This seems to be the case with the MinGW compiler therefore the precision was way lower which caused the delta not to change. Anyways thanks for the tip, I'll check the physics article out and refactor the physics code!

Comment: @KevinKuegler Again, none of this matters. Your assumption that two calls to obtain the clock value will differ is **fundamentally wrong**. Worse yet, this doesn't even have to be a monotonic clock, so your clock can go backwards - usually on context switches.

Comment: @KevinKuegler Besides, if your task gets delayed for whatever reason, you might be getting time deltas that are very long and will make the simulation step's result useless. I'm not referring to anyone's article, I'm just referring to the fact that your implementation is broken at a very fundamental level. Don't fight it. Do it right. It'll be much easier.

Comment: @KevinKuegler You have an option of resetting the reference time in the engine once the engine lags too far behind, for whatever reason.

Comment: Hmm okay sorry then I misunderstood your answer. Im going try to understand everything and redo the logic. When Im done I shall post the result for reference, so thanks!